# How to POST this API code in Python 3 with Requests module? Keep getting 405 error

Tags: python, token, python-requests

I want to use the API for a link shortener site. I know the example given is in **curl** and that `-H` means there's a header as well as `PUT` means it's posting, but I can't seem to get the result I want no matter how much I try. All I can do is either get a 405 error or break it.

I am on Windows with Python 3 and do have `requests` installed already.

> For developers Shorte.st prepared API which returns responses in JSON format.
>
> Currently there is one method which can be used to shorten links on behalf of your account.
>
> Take a look on the sample below to learn how to use our API.
>
> ```sh
> curl -H "public-api-token: (my token)" -X PUT -d
> "urlToShorten=google.com" https://api.shorte.st/v1/data/url
> ```
>
> When received,
>
> ```js
> {"status":"ok","shortenedUrl":"http:\/\/sh.st\/XXXX"}
> ```

I have tried a few things namely,

```
import requests
import json
gogo = { 'public-api-token: (my token)' : 'urlToShorten=google.com'}
yep = requests.post('https://api.shorte.st/v1/data/url',   
data=json.dumps(gogo))
print (yep.text)
```

shows me an HTML webpage with error 405.

```
import requests
import json
gogo = { 'public-api-token' : '(my token)', 'urlToShorten=' : 'google.com'}
yep = requests.post('https://api.shorte.st/v1/data/url',    
data=json.dumps(gogo))
print (yep.text)
```

Also shows me a webpage with error 405.

I now know the `-H` is for headers and am using this while still just gets me the page.

```
import requests
import json

headers = { 'public-api-token' : '(my token)' }
gogo = {"urlToShorten" : "google.com"}
yep = requests.post('https://api.shorte.st/v1/data/url',  
data=json.dumps(gogo), headers=headers)
print (yep.text)
```

and another attempt another 405

```
gogo = {"public-api-token: (my token)" : "urlToShorten=google.com"}
yep = requests.post('https://api.shorte.st/v1/data/url', 
data=json.dumps(gogo))
print (yep.text)
```

Even this just gives me a full html page/405 if I take off the text.

```
headers = { "public-api-token: (my token)" : "urlToShorten=google.com" }
yep = requests.post('https://api.shorte.st/v1/data/url', headers=headers)
print (yep.text)
```

Comment: You're doing PUT in the curl but POST in Python. Did you try `requests.put`?

Comment: Gives me a JSON not serializable with Carlton's example and general .put gives 400 error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are putting your PUT payload in the headers. Put it in the *body* instead. Your payload is **not** JSON, so there is no need to try and treat it as such.

The headers need to be specified as a dictionary with the header name and token as key and value. The parameters for the payload can be treated in the same way.

You are also using the wrong `requests` method; to send a PUT request, use the [`put` function](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.put) instead:

```
headers = {'public-api-token': '(my token)'}
payload = {'urlToShorten': 'google.com'}
response = requests.put(
    'https://api.shorte.st/v1/data/url',
    data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.json())
```

The `response` object has a [`json()` method](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.json) to decode the JSON data returned by the API; it'll give you the Python data structure corresponding to the JSON text.

I don't have a token for the service you are using; I created a demo using the [`httpbin.org` service](http://httpbin.org/); it reflects what was sent as a JSON response:

```
>>> import requests
>>> headers = {'public-api-token': '(my token)'}
>>> payload = {'urlToShorten': 'google.com'}
>>> response = requests.put(
...     'http://httpbin.org/put',
...         data=payload, headers=headers)
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(response.json())
{u'args': {},
 u'data': u'',
 u'files': {},
 u'form': {u'urlToShorten': u'google.com'},
 u'headers': {u'Accept': u'*/*',
              u'Accept-Encoding': u'gzip, deflate',
              u'Content-Length': u'23',
              u'Content-Type': u'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              u'Host': u'httpbin.org',
              u'Public-Api-Token': u'(my token)',
              u'User-Agent': u'python-requests/2.5.0 CPython/2.7.9 Darwin/14.1.0'},
 u'json': None,
 u'origin': u'94.118.96.0',
 u'url': u'http://httpbin.org/put'}
```

If you compare that to the output produced for `curl` sending a `PUT` request to the same URL you'll see the same results are produced:

```
$ curl -H "public-api-token: (my token)" -X PUT \
     -d "urlToShorten=google.com" http://httpbin.org/put
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "urlToShorten": "google.com"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Content-Length": "23", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Public-Api-Token": "(my token)", 
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.37.1"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "94.118.96.0", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/put"
}
```

Comment: Wow, this worked. Thank you for your help. I'll take this answer to heart for future reference. Thank you!